# How to add JS function programmatically and call it

Tags: javascript, python, html, function, dynamic

After adding JS reference (programmatically), right image, I want consequently to call my function with onclick event or with selenium(py). I see in DEV tool my reference is added but I am not able to call my function from embedded reference. THX
[image]

```
driverEdge.execute_script('my_function();')
```

Error: javascript error: my_function is not defined

(FYI: All script works if the page already has my reference embedded )

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround. Store JS logic in file. Read content and let it execute.

`driverEdge.execute_script("content_of_file_with_logic.js")`